# Why is my code slow (does it even work)? [Project Euler 12][Python 3.3]

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I wrote this code for [Project Euler #12](http://projecteuler.net/problem=12). It's very slow (or doesn't work) and I found another code that is very similar and gets the answer immediately.
My code:

```
import math

def get_triangular(nth):
    return sum(range(1,nth+1))

def get_divisors_count(n):
    divisors = 0
    for a in range(1,math.ceil(n/2)+1):
        if n%a == 0:
            divisors += 1
    return divisors

a = 1
while(True):
    if get_divisors_count(get_triangular(a)) > 500:
        print(a)
    a += 1
```

The code I found on Stack Overflow:

```
import math

def main():
    l = []
    one = 0
    a = 1
    b = 2
    while one == 0:
        a = a + b 
        b += 1
        l = []

        sqrt_a = int(math.sqrt(a))

        for x in range(1, sqrt_a + 1):
            if a % x == 0:
                l.append(x)
                if x < math.sqrt(a):
                    l.append(a // x)
                if len(l) > 500:
                    # print(a)
                    one = 1

    print(a, b, len(l))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You may want to consider a few things for debugging this yourself: (a) test them with smaller numbers, like 100 instead of 500, and (b) add a counter that you increment each time through the inner loop and print out at the end, to figure out how many more repetitions you're doing than the other version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your program never ends. You have a `while True` loop without a `break`, or any other way to exit the loop. The other code you posted has `while one == 0` instead of `while True`, and it sets `one = 1` as soon as `len(l) > 500`. That's a little awkward, but it works.

So:

```
a = 1
while(True):
    if get_divisors_count(get_triangular(a)) > 500:
        print(a)
        break
    a += 1
```

This is still pretty slow, but not infinitely slow.

---

The next biggest difference is that you're counting up to n/2+1, while the other code is counting to sqrt(n), and counting each divisor twice. (Why does this work? Think about it: If `a` is a divisor of `n`, then `n/a` is too, and exactly one of them must be less than `sqrt(n)` unless they're both equal to it.)

---

You're also wasting a bit of time in a few areas where the other program doesn't, like calculating `sum(range(1, nth+1))` over and over, instead of keeping a running sum and doing `running_sum += a`. On the other hand, you're already saving some time by just keeping a count of divisors instead of building a list of them and then taking its length.

But those are minor compared to the previous issues. At least your program now has the same algorithmic complexity, `O(N**1.5)`, instead of `O(N**2)` (or infinite); on my machine, it runs in 15.3 seconds vs. 12.1.

If you really want to make it faster, there are two major options:

1. Look at it mathematically and see if there's a better way to solve this than brute force. (Hint: Can see how prime factorization would help you here?)
2. Figure out if there's information you can memoize (cache) that would help out. For example, if you want to count the factors of 96, and you already have the factors of 24, does that do you any good? What if you have only the factor count? Or only the prime factors?

Comment: I modified my code, made it even a bit faster than the other code. But I still need to look closer at the sqrt thing, I don't understand it well and I think it doesn't work in every case. `import math

def get_divisor_count(n):
    divisors = 0
    sqrtn = int(n**0.5)
    for a in range(1,sqrtn+1):
        if n%a == 0:
            divisors += 1
            if a < sqrtn:
                divisors += 1
    return divisors

x = 0
y = 1
while(True):
    x += y
    y += 1
    if get_divisor_count(x) > 500:
        print(x)
        break`

Comment: @wikku: Trying to get code into a comment on SO is pointless; it will eat all your whitespace. Either edit your question, or post it somewhere like pastebin.com and put a link here.

Comment: @wikku: Meanwhile, it's very easy to end up with off-by-one errors with `sqrt`, so think that through, and if you're not sure, write some test code to see what your function does when given various values (where you already know the right answer).